# GLib: Replacement for deprecated g_tree_traverse() function?

Tags: compilation, glib

recently we planned to upgrade glib library to latest version : `2.64`

We have built the library and try to use the same in our build infrastructure. While running build we are failing lot of warnings with symbol 'g_tree_travers' as follows :-

```
warning: 'g_tree_traverse' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

Not sure what we supposed to use instead of `g_tree_traverse`, How could we fix the issue?

Comment: have you looked in the docs https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Balanced-Binary-Trees.html#g-tree-traverse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying from [the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Balanced-Binary-Trees.html#g-tree-traverse) (as suggested by Jussi):

> `g_tree_traverse` has been deprecated since version 2.2 and should not be used in newly-written code.
>
> The order of a balanced tree is somewhat arbitrary. If you just want to visit all nodes in sorted order, use [`g_tree_foreach()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Balanced-Binary-Trees.html#g-tree-foreach) instead. If you really need to visit nodes in a different order, consider using an n-ary tree.

Comment: Thanks Philip, We can use 'g_tree_foreach' , But the functionality of this function is different than 'g_tree_traverse', I notice that in g_tree_traverse function we are passing 'traverse_type' argument, Where in 'g_tree_foreach' we are not sending 'traverse_type' by default it traverses all nodes in sorted order. In our case when we are using 'g_tree_traverse' , we are using traverse_type as a combination of G_IN_ORDER, G_PRE_ORDER ...etc how could we achieve the same with g_tree_foreach. Could you please share some example code here?

Comment: `GTree` is documented as implementing a *sorted* balanced binary tree, and is optimised for sorted access. Doing pre-, in- and post-order traversal means you presumably don’t care about the nodes actually being sorted. As the documentation says, consider using an n-ary tree instead, such as [`GNode`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-N-ary-Trees.html).